# Workaround for passing by reference in java

Tags: java

From this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X):

Find the kth to last element of a singly linked list.
One of the proposed solutions is as follows:

```
  public class IntWrapper{
    public int value = 0;
  }

  Node nthToLast3(Node head, int k, IntWrapper i){
    if (head == null){
      return null;
    }
    Node node = nthToLast3(head.next, k, i);
    i.value = i.value + 1;
    if (i.value == k){
      return head;
    }
    return node;
  }
```

Why do we have to create the int Wrapper class and can't we use an int directly?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Actually, it's not. Nowhere near. He's asking why you have to create a wrapper, while the question you linked is asking if Java is pass-by-reference or pass-by-value. While they are related, they are nothing like duplicates.

Comment: It is not clear in this code what the wrapper wants to do. Actually it looks more like a job for field. However, if you want to return more than one value (something you would do with modifying an out variable) you basically have the option to return a result (tupel) object  `class NodeAndPosition { int pos; Node node; }` or modify one of the referenced objects.

Comment: Couldn't you use `Integer`, which is a built-in wrapper for `int`?

Comment: @mbomb007 `Integer` is immutable. You can't use it as a holder.

Comment: @newbiedoodle You have to have the wrapper... because Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: FYI, sometimes I work around this by creating a one-element array instead of declaring a new class.  Thus `Node nthToLast3(Node head, int k, int[] i)` ... `i[0] = i[0] + 1;`  It's a bit ugly, so I try not to do this for production code.  I prefer the wrapper class.  However, I believe Android uses this kind of thing in its API.

Comment: @chrylis ...Yes? What about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this trick does, is to wrap an `int` (native type) in an object (`Object` derived type). Everything is passed by value in `Java`, and for objects, the value of the reference is passed as an argument, in a sense (think of it like a pointer value in `C/C++`, for example).

Comment: So, since objects are passed by value as well, then I still don't understand why the value would be updated? (I don't get the analogy with c pointers)

Comment: Objects are not passed by value. Object references are passed by value. It is like saying you are passing the value of an object pointer, at least this is what I think of it.

Answer (score 2):

The author uses `IntWrapper` instead of an `int` because he wants to achieve persistent state for a value between the callers and callees.

A modification to the `int` member of an `IntWrapper` instance in a callee will be visible to a caller.

With a plain `int`, that's not possible because it's a primitive type, and hence it will be passed by value (it will be 'copied' if I may).

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible in Java to pass primitive values by reference. This is a restriction on the language itself.

Technically, the only things you can pass into methods are "primitives, and pointers to objects". The latter also being a form of primitive.  Java possesses neither references nor const object passing.

Answer (score -1):

The point is that you want to be able to set the value of `i`.

`int`s are in Java implemented as primitive data, they are passed-by-value. This means that the following code doesn't set `a`:

```
public void Foo () {
    int a = 5;
    System.out.println(a);//prints 5
    setA(a);
    System.out.println(a);//prints 5
}

public void setA (int a) {
    a = 3;
}
```

Java copies the *value* of the variable on the stack and the copy is modified leaving the original `a` untouched.

By using a `Wrapper`, you store the `int` in an object. Since `object`s are passed-by-value from a "variable perspective", or passed-by-reference from the objects perspective, you refer to an `object` that contains an `int`. In other words, `aw` referers to the same instance. Because you **copied** the **reference** an not the **object**. Changes made by the *callee* are thus reflected in the view of the *caller*.

```
public void Foo () {
    IntWrapper aw = new IntWrapper();
    aw.value = 5;
    System.out.println(aw.value);//prints 5
    setA(aw);
    System.out.println(aw.value);//prints 3
}

public void setA (IntWrapper aw) {
    aw.value = 3;
}
```

This is a useful hack in Java when you want to return multiple values or modify a variable of the *caller*.

**C#** alternatively provides the `ref` keyword, that enable call-by-reference for primitive values.

Comment: Probably because of the "pass by reference" claim.

Comment: @Keppil: Well `object`s are passed by reference... Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: <- just the messenger. No shooting please.

Comment: @Keppil, sure but as far as I know, the claim is correct, I don't see why this raises issues... :s

Comment: Java does not support pass by reference. Object references are passed by value, which is completely different. Pass by reference means that you can write a swap method that swaps two objects. This is completely impossible in Java.

Comment: There is no call-by-reference in Java.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: no, pass by reference doesn't imply you have any tools to **modify** the reference. That would by *pass-by-pointer*. There is a clear difference between a reference and a pointer. It depends on how you see an `object`. If you see an object only as the *reference* to that object, it is indeed, pass-by-value. But if you see objects as the objects themselves, it is pass-by-value.

Comment: That is why safest way to say it is that Java is *pass-by-value-of-reference*.

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @IanMcLaird: Yeah, I read that article, as specified in the previous comment, it depends on how you see an `object`. If you see an `object` **only** as the reference to that object, it is indeed pass-by-value, otherwise if you see an `object` as the object itself, it is pass-by-reference. Apperently `C#` sees it as pass-by-reference, since otherwise the `ref` keyword should be badly designed.

Comment: Passing by reference doesn't apply to objects, it applies to variables. [My own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24546764/438154) to that question explains this (as well as the actual thing that is passed in Java). Although, I understand what you are trying to express in your answer, the parts concerning passing by reference are wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: well I slightly softened the claim. But it realy depends on how you see an object. If you read *Modern Compiler Implementation*, it is clear that terms are sloppy defined. Literally it is true it is passed-by-value, but it really conflicts with almost any introduction course on Java where objects are represented as real objects...

Comment: The `ref` keyword in C# allows true pass by reference. You can do this in C#: `public static void Swap(ref string a, ref string b) { string temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }`. Then the caller can do this: `string x = "X", y = "Y"; Swap(ref x, ref y); Console.WriteLine(x);` and the output is `Y`. This is completely impossible in Java.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: well I mentioned this in the end of the answer. And softened the claim about call-by-reference in the Java part... As mentioned before, it depends on whether the perspective is the variable or the object. And for `strings` what you say holds, but not for `int`'s, you do a value swap, not a reference swap. A reference swap would imply that your `references` point to something different. You load different values in the variables that happen to be each others... That's something different... In both C#/Java, `string`s are objects after all, so double reference...

Comment: It does hold for `ints`. Try it. `public static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b) { int temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }`. Then use the method: `int x = 1, y = 2; Swap(ref x, ref y); Console.WriteLine(x);` and the output is 2. Again, completely impossible in Java.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: if you had read the comment more carefully, you would see that the comment specified that you do a *swap-by-value* and not a *swap-by-reference*. This means that when you leave the `swap` function, `x` doesn't refer to what `y` was originally refering and vice versa. This can have serious concequences in the event of cascading call-by-reference calls. But also makes it clear how completely schizophrenic these concepts actually are...